# Detecting water (via resistance) between two metal probes using 3.3v MCU's ADC

Tags: adc

For the past few days, I've been going in circles trying to plan a circuit to detect water between a pair of metal probes (or more precisely, between several pairs of stainless steel probes approximately 1 inch apart connected in parallel, and two "water sensor" circuit boards that consist of two zig-zagging 50-mil traces separated by 50-mil space).

The fundamental problem is, I don't really understand the finer points of Ohm's Law (or at least, the parts that might deviate from what I suspect is actually a simplified  special case... when you aren't just talking about a simple resistor limiting current between +3.3v and ground).

Consider the following circuit (in series), using a 3.3v ESP32:

- GPIO pin that's normally left floating as an input (to minimize galvanic corrosion of the probes), but configured for output & taken high (to 3.3v) shortly before triggering ADC conversion.
- 82-100 ohm resistor (to limit the maximum possible current flowing between the GPIO and ADC pins to 40mA or less, even if there ends up being a dead short and zero ohms between the probes
- a pair of probes (normally, with air insulating them... potentially, with tap water insulating them a bit less)... and two or more such pairs connected in parallel (so there could be current flowing between none of them, between one pair, or between multiple pairs)
- ADC input pin on the ESP32

The things that have me scratching my head:

- If you assume 3.3v on the GPIO pin and *only* 82 ohms between it and the ADC pin, how many volts will the ADC sense/measure/see?
- Does a 12-bit ADC actually have enough "headroom" to meaningfully sense the difference between all-but-infinite resistance (82 ohms + an inch of open air) and whatever resistance you'd likely encounter between two stainless-steel probes immersed in tap water? Or at best, would you end up with readings that just jittered between something like 0 to 5 and 2 to 7 (out of 4095), and were so close and mostly-overlapping, you almost might as well randomly flip a coin to decide whether or not there's water present?

I suspect that the impedance of the ADC *itself* is an important detail that I don't know the value of.

I'm kind of embarrassed to be asking this, because this is apparently considered to be an absurdly-simple circuit... but all the examples I've seen basically consist of a voltage comparator whose output directly triggers a piezo, as opposed to using a MCU to measure it through a proper ADC. I'm not sure whether that's because the amount of voltage at the far end would be too low to reliably measure with a 12-bit ADC, or just because prior to just a few years ago, the very *idea* of using a MCU and ADC for something like this would have been prohibitively expensive overkill (instead of, like, $9 for an ESP32-C3 that you need *anyway* for the wi-fi link).

Do I actually need to do something like have the ESP32's 3.3v GPIO trigger a MOSFET switching 5.0v, then amplify the other end with an op-amp and/or run it through an optocoupler or something? Or am I **way** overthinking something that isn't nearly as complicated as I'm making it?

Comment: Can you please draw a diagram, a schematic? Because, feeding 3.3V into ADC will make it read 3.3V. Feeding some other voltage makes it read that voltage. Unless impedance is too high and the ADC can't read it. So the ADC by itself cannot measure resistance in any meaningful way, you need to convert your sensor to output voltage.

Comment: What "finer points of Ohm's Law" do you have in mind? For >99% of the cases you will ever encounter, Ohm's Law works exactly as its simple form seems to suggest.

Comment: @TooTea is right. If you see Ohm's law stops working, it means, whatever you thought was resistance, is not, or at least is not anymore.

Comment: The problem is, I can't figure out what the voltage would be at the ADC end after starting out as 3.3v, passing through an 82-100 ohm resistor, then an inch of water with some presently-unknown but non-infinite resistance. Ohm's law tells me how much current is reaching the ADC, but seemingly says nothing about the voltage drop across the resistor and water-between-the-probes. Every water-detection circuit I've seen uses voltage-comparators, so a voltage drop IS presumably occurring... but I don't understand how to predict how many volts the ADC itself will see.

Comment: Is this to detect if water is in an area that is normally dry or is the probe(s) immersed in water all the time? If it is immersed in water all the time you will erode one of the electrodes due to electrolytic corrosion. Plus, the resistance reading will change as bubbles form and break off the surface of the electrodes.

Comment: As an additional complication you will get corrosion on the electrodes due to electrolytic action if you maintain the voltage all the time. It is better if you only activate the 3.3V to the sensor just when you are performing the detection. This can easily be done by using another GPIO as the 3.3V source. It is even better to periodically alternate the voltage to counteract corrosion. This is a bit more complicated.

Comment: @qrk It's solely to detect the presence of water in an area that's normally (and hopefully, always WILL be) dry. I'm taking advantage of a temporarily-open wall to put some sensors (using the term loosely, since they're REALLY just a bunch of passive circuit boards with traces intended to be shorted-out by water) below a cluster of pipes and fittings that are at risk for future pinhole leaks.

Comment: @Kevin White that's why I'm using a GPIO instead of connecting it directly to the battery, and only planning to power it up to check every 30-60 seconds. Normally, the only moisture it encounters will be ambient humidity in a perpetually air-conditioned house. If it **actually** ends up submerged someday, corrosion & bubbles happening after that point will honestly be the least of my problems ;-)

Comment: Some water has VERY high resistance. More than just Ohm's law should be considered. Try looking at some alternatives: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/488524/how-to-detect-distilled-water

Comment: @glen_geek Any water it detects will be tap water that's so hard, you can almost walk on it. Plus, it'll probably have dissolved boric acid in it as well. Anytime I have a wall open, I take advantage of the opportunity to dump a container or two of Raid boric acid powder inside to kill any bugs that end up walking across it. If a future pipe leak fills the cavity with water that isn't initially conductive enough for the ADC to notice, the boric acid dissolving into that water within a few minutes should make it quite a bit more conductive. :-)

Comment: @glen_geek also, the sensor will be sitting on top of electrical tape lining steel studs above a concrete slab. AFAIK, just about any indirect method of detecting water (hall effect, microwave, ultrasound, etc) would be too overwhelmed by the nearby presence of concrete & steel to work, or would have to be so far above the studs, I'd need *inches* of water trapped inside the wall to trigger it. And I'd never depend on anything involving float switches... I know multiple people who've had air conditioner drip pans flood with failed float switches that were supposed to detect it, but didn't.

Comment: Get your multimeter on Ohms and measure the water resistance. That value should give you an idea of the resistance to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you assume 3.3v on the GPIO pin and only 82 ohms between it and the ADC pin, how many volts will the ADC sense/measure/see?

The 82 Ω to the ADC will form a potential divider with the input impedance of the ADC. I would expect this to be in the order of 100 kΩ to several MΩ. The datasheet should give this value. In any case the if the ratio was 82 Ω : 82 kΩ (1 : 100) the ADC would see 99% of 3.3 V (which is fine). A higher input impedance would improve this further.

> Does a 12-bit ADC actually have enough "headroom" to meaningfully sense the difference between all-but-infinite resistance (82 ohms + an inch of open air) and whatever resistance you'd likely encounter between two stainless-steel probes immersed in tap water?

"Headroom" isn't quite the right word as the dry reading will be 100%. "Resolution" or "span" of readings might be better. This would be very easy to test with a 3.3 V supply, your multimeter and test probes. Check the open-circuit voltage (3.3 V) and then apply the various test conditions to your probe while measuring the voltage.

I suspect that you'll find that 82 Ω is quite a stiff pull-up and that a wet probe may struggle to pull the voltage down significantly so be prepared to check with 1 kΩ and 10 kΩ.

> Or at best, would you end up with readings that just jittered between something like 0 to 5 and 2 to 7 (out of 4095), ...

More likely > 4000, if anything (he said without doing any tests).

> I suspect that the impedance of the ADC itself is an important detail that I don't know the value of.

It will be high relative to what you're measuring so I wouldn't worry about it (unless you end up with very high pull-up resistors). That information *must* be available from the datasheet?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPupBN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Equivalent circuit. R<sub>PU</sub> is the pull-up resistor.*

> So you're saying that the circuit would NOT be, GPIO (outputting 3.3v) -> resistor (limiting current) -> probe -> water -> probe -> ADC pin?

No. That wouldn't work. You want to create a potential divider. The voltage at the ADC input will be

$$ V_{ADC} = 3.3 \frac {R_{SOIL}} {R_{PU} + R_{SOIL}} $$

Now it should be clear that the ADC input impedance makes very little difference to the reading.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying that the circuit would NOT be, GPIO (outputting 3.3v) -> resistor (limiting current) -> probe -> water -> probe -> ADC pin?

Comment: @Bitbang3r That is what I said too. You can't put 0 ohms to say 1 megaohm between 3.3V and ADC input and expect anything else than 3.3V as there is no current and no voltage drop. Basic ohm's law.

Comment: @Bitbang3r: See the update.

Comment: @Transistor ah, this clarifies things a lot! Thanks!

Comment: @Bitbang3r, good. Wait a day or two to encourage other responses and then accept the one which best answers your question. Otherwise your question will periodically pop up in the main index as unsolved.

Comment: In a similar context I used an Rpu of 47 kohm and added a capacitor of 1 uF in parallel to suppress pickup of some AC fields around the wiring. The sensor was a one square Inch PCB with interleaved 100 mil pads.